# Python transfer excel formatting between two Excel documents

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'd like to copy the formatting between two Excel sheets in python.

Here is the situation:

I have a script that effectively "alters" (ie overwrites) an excel file by opening it using pd.ExcelWriter, then updates values in the rows. Finally, file is overwritten using ExcelWriter.

The Excel file is printed/shared/read by humans between updates done by the code. Humans will do things like change number formatting, turn on/off word wrap, and alter column widths.

My goal is the code updates should only alter the content of the file, not the formatting of the columns.

Is there a way I can read/store/write the sheet format within python so the output file has the same column formatting as the input file?

Here's the basic idea of what I am doing right now:

```
df_in= pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx")    
# Here is where I'd like to read in format of the first sheet of this file
xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_out = do_update(df_in)
df_out.to_excel(xlwriter,'sheet1')
# Here is where I'd like to apply the format I read earlier to the sheet
xlwriter.save()
```

Note: I have played with xlsxwriter.set_column and add_format. As far as I can tell, these don't help me read the format from the current file

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses `xlrd` package for parsing Excel documents to DataFrames.

Interoperability between other `xlsx` packages and `xlrd` could be problematic when it comes to the data structure used to represent formatting information.

I suggest using `openpyxl` as your engine when instantiating `pandas.ExcelWriter`. It comes with reader and writer classes that are interoperable.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles.stylesheet import apply_stylesheet
from openpyxl.reader.excel import ExcelReader

xlreader = ExcelReader('myfile.xlsx', read_only=True)
xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df_in = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx")
df_out = do_update(df_in)
df_out.to_excel(xlwriter,'sheet1')

apply_stylesheet(xlreader.archive, xlwriter.book)

xlwriter.save()
```